# Observable return collection of collection

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm just starting to learn `Observable` and all it variations and run into some strange problem. Here it is:

I have a WCF service declaration (after 'Add Service reference' process):

```
public IAsyncResult ReceiveAllUsersAsync(AsyncCallback Callback, object State)
{
    // Do some work
}
```

and here the closing one:

```
public IObservable<User> EndReceiveAllUsers(IAsyncResult AsyncResultHandler)
{
   // Do some work (actuall y it's a:  return AsyncResultHandler.EndInvoke();
   // return IObservable<User>
}
```

as you can see the `EndReceiveAllUsers` return collection of `User`'s

next I run an RX like so:

```
// This will not owrk
Func<IObservable<User>> callWcfService = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<IObservable<User>>(BeginReceiveAll, EndReceiveAll);

// Actuall Func<> signature is:
Func<IObservable< IObservable<User> >> callWcfService = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<IObservable<User>>(BeginReceiveAll, EndReceiveAll);
```

but the problem is that whatever returned from `Observable.FromAsyncPattern` is `IObservable<>` of `IObservable<User>`. Actually it return `IObservable< IObservable<User> >`. How I could return just one result of `IObservable<User>` and not the collection of result

Comment: @TimS. Please see my first comment to @ Vlad -> Actually I receive **collection** of `User` and that could not be casted to **single** `User`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the behavior you want, but to answer your question directly, you can simply concatenate each sequence of users after the completion of the last one:

```
IObservable<IObservable<User>> tooMuch = callWcfService();
IObservable<User> justRight = tooMuch.Concat();
```

Comment: .Concat(), .Merge() and .Switch() all are operators that can work with nested sequences. Where the sequences are serial (no overlapping data) then they all act the same. When the data in the sequences can overlap they have very different behaviour. Be sure to check the output of the WCF service. Normally what people expect is actually .Merge()  - HTH Lee

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

`Observable` abstracts the multiple calls to `ReceiveAllUsersAsync`/`EndReceiveAllUsers` for you, so each time you get a whole `IEnumerable<User>`, it's produced as a whole by `Observable`. So if you want to produce the `User`s one by one, you need to switch to functions that produce users one at a time. `ReceiveAllUsersAsync` is not the function you need, as it waits until all the users are obtained, and gives them all back in a pack.

The one thing you can do is to convert the obtained `IEnumerable<User>` to `IObservable<User>`, but this will again behave in such a way: (1) get all the users under the hood, (2) produce all of them without pause -- which is not what you expect from a decent `IObservable<>`.

---

Old answer, for reference:
Looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212031%28v=vs.103%29.aspx:

```
public static Func<IObservable<TResult>> FromAsyncPattern<TResult>(
    Func<AsyncCallback, Object, IAsyncResult> begin,
    Func<IAsyncResult, TResult> end
)
```

So you perhaps just need `Observable.FromAsyncPattern<User>`, as `User` is your `TResult`.

Comment: That's generally correct answer - but the point is that my `EndXXX` function already return `IObservable<User>` - I should just pass it back to `Func<>`. And your suggestion obviously lead to casting error: Can not implicity convert `System.IObservable<User>` to `User`. I guess it happens when EndXXX return collection and then FromAsync trying to wrap it to `TResult` - in my case it single `User` - and it can not be done

Comment: @Jasper: look, you want the `User`s to appear one by one, right? this means that `EndXXX` function should deliver an individual `User` and not the whole: having `IObservable` when the operation is already over doesn't make much sense -- right?

Comment: @ Vlad no :) I run the service -> receive the answer (in this case especially wrap it `IObservable<>` collection). When (whole collection) received I'll sort it and pass it down the pipe. I choose `IObservable` because most of the functions down-the-pipe will expect `IObservable<>` to work on...

Comment: @Jasper: oh, I see. Then you can just follow the advice in the old answer: use `Observable.FromAsyncPattern<User>`.

Comment: Eee.... My first comment was that I can not convert returned answer `IObservable<User>`  to **just** `User` - it could not be casted !

Comment: @Jasper: and you don't want to, because that `IEnumerable<User>` already contains _all_ the users.

Comment: @Jasper: But if you are okay with getting the whole bunch of users at once, you can convert `IEnumerable<User>` to `IObservable<User>` with [`enumerable.ToObservable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212140%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

Comment: @ Vlad - thank you. Yo was logically correct. Actually I found scenario where just what I want implemented: http://blog.john-thiriet.com/en/2011/07/reactive-extensions-simple-asynchronous-repository/   - I'm using Observable in a wrong way.